# What are the South African words for crisps and French Fries?

Tags: dialects, south-african-english, localization

Consider Exhibit A.

[image]

Consider Exhibit B.

[image]

In England, A is referred to as 'Chips' and B is referred to as 'Crisps'.

In the United States A is referred to as 'French Fries' and B is referred to as 'Chips'.

In Australia A is referred to as 'Chips' and B is referred to as 'Chips'.

My question is: **What are the South African words for Crisps and French Fries?**

(Curious about Canada too, but will stick with SA for now).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato_chip#Nomenclature

Comment: The answers to both questions (South African and Canadian names for fries) appear to be in the Wikipedia article on [french fries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_fries).

Comment: We in Australia sometimes call 'Exhibit B' crisps too, just not very often. Well, at least I've heard it in Melbourne where I live.

Comment: You had me at 'Consider'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a South African, I can confirm that Exhibit A is definitely referred to as **chips**, in fact, we also use the term **[slap chips](http://tastykitchen.com/recipes/sidedishes/south-african-slap-chips-french-fries/)**, which means chips that are slightly soggy as they've been bathed in vinegar; so **chips** is definitely common usage. See [this menu](http://www.nandos.co.za/menu) from *Nandos*, a South African company of some renown, which uses **chips** too.

**Fries**, on the otherhand, are also common usage, but tend to be generally more associated to American-style fast food chains as is shown [here](http://www.mcdonalds.co.za/sites/default/files/MCDELIVERY_MENU.pdf), although in common parlance the words are interchangeable.

Moving on to Exhibit B, I'll again reference a pre-eminent manufacturer of these comestibles, in this case, *Simba*. *Simba* [refers to their product as chips too](http://www.simba.co.za/brands/simba), and so this is common parlance for items shown in Exhibit B, especially given that Simba's market-share is arguably the largest for these products in South Africa.

The term **crisps**, however, is well understood, and is certainly used when differentiation between these products is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Exhibit A are known as chips: slapchips (soft, soggy and covered in vinegar) if bought from the store, chips if made at home.

Exhibit b are known as chips or by school kids as simbas after the brand Simba Chips.

Answer (score -2):

Both these "A" and "B"  are referred to as "Chips" in South Africa

Comment: Hello, Boinneth. As tchrist has said, 'We are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely [statements that may possibly be no more than] personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers.' And the Wikipedia article Stephie mentions says that your statement is only true for 'some parts of South Africa'.